# Код выдает ошибку в классе почему?

Tags: javascript

```js
function f(phrase) {
  return class {
    sayHi() { console.log(phrase) }
  }
}

class User extends f("Привет") {}

new User().sayHi();
```

1. Код не выдаст ошибку

```js
function f(phrase) {
  return class {
    sayHi() { alert(phrase) }
  }
}

class User extends f("Привет");

new User().sayHi();
```

1. Код выдаст ошибку
2. Почему ?

Comment: Вероятно, потому что строка `class User extends f("Привет");` не создаёт класс. Нужно хотя бы пустое тело оставить, а не совсем его убирать

Comment: @InDevX я  возвращаю класс а  не создаю его

Comment: Вы не возвращаете его, а определяете (создаёте) этой строкой.

Comment: @InDevX спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extends` является частью [определения класса](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#prod-ClassDeclaration).

```
ClassDeclaration[Yield, Await, Default]:
    class BindingIdentifier[?Yield, ?Await] ClassTail[?Yield, ?Await]
```

где *ClassTail* имеет следующую структуру

```
ClassTail[Yield, Await]:
    ClassHeritage[?Yield, ?Await]opt { ClassBody[?Yield, ?Await]opt }
```

Отсюда видно, что [**обязательно**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#prod-ClassTail) указывать тело класса, как минимум пустым блоком.

При этом `extend` указан в *ClassHeritage*

```
ClassHeritage[Yield, Await]:
    extends LeftHandSideExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
```

Если применить к примеру в вопросе

```
class User extends f("Привет") {}
```

*ClassHeritage* - `extends f("Привет")` и далее должно следовать тело класса.

Так как во втором случае тела нет появляется ошибка.

Comment: 1) я не знаю английский 2) тело класса я указываю для class User 3) фигурные скобки не имеют никакого отношения анонимному классу который возвращает функция f 4) Правильно ?

Comment: @user304926, обновил ответ

Comment: скажите пожалуйста а можно сказать что я  в пункте 2 и 3 я правильно понял ?

Comment: @user304926, именно об этом вторая часть ответа про ClassHeritage

Comment: вообщем я недавно начал изучать программирование и js в частности; думаю посыл понятен (без обид ) ... P.S. спасибо что потратили свое время